# TCPDF takes 10 minutes to generate a 40 page pdf file

Tags: php, mysql, performance, tcpdf

I have a report generation PHP program which used to work fine before. I have used 2 3rd party libraries in the program: Google image chart library ( returns image if I supply values in url ) and tcpdf ( for pdf generation ). I am using mysql not mysqli for queries. There are lots of queries and loops in the page.

Before it used to take less than 3 minutes to generate the report, I am using an ajax call to generate the report which gives a completed message once the file generation is done. This program saves the pdf file in a folder and I have a link with same name to download the file.

Recently when I checked its not generating properly.

Error was TCPDF unable to get the image. This was because of the google chart library not returning the image properly. When I access the chart url in browser it gives me the image without any issue but If I give it in an image src inside a php file, its not showing. So I decided to save the file in a folder using functions like file_get_contents,file_put_contents and link it in image src. This part is now working correctly I can see the image.

But now the problem is it is taking a lot of time to generate the report, even in  local environment. I tried to generate the report without the chart priniting but even then its taking time. In between it was 25 minutes n all and now its close to 10 minutes to generate a 40 page pdf file.

I really don't know why its taking so much time. All of this was working fine before and now its not working. Only thing that changed was google image chart library but now even without(commented that part and checked) that also its taking time.

**How do I speed this up ? Is there any way to check which part of program is slow.**

Tried xdebug but its output file is more than 400 mb and webgrind is not able to process it.

Please help.

Comment: With respect, you haven't given us much to work with in this question. Please consider editing it to give more details.

Comment: Please check now. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out.

The issue is with the database, one of the tables has more 120000 records in it. Deleted irrelevant records, not a permanent solution but now it generates the same thing in 2.1 minutes.

Now I can't do the same thing in my production server. I would love to get your inputs on how to optimize the database.

Thank You

Comment: Still not enough to work with.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` that gathers the data.

Comment: This is likely to be solvable with well-chosen MySQL indexes. You can add, change, and delete MySQL indexes without affecting the data in the server. Read this http://use-the-index-luke.com/ and then, if you still need help, ask another question.  Like Rick said, you will need to give us the poorly performing queries, the table definitions and the EXPLAIN  results. from those queries.

Answer (score 1):

Your next step is to troubleshoot performance.

*Is TCPDF doing a lot of work you don't need done?* Presumably you've seen the tips from TCPDF's author on increasing performance, and put them into practice.  http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php

*Are some of your MySQL queries inefficient?* Obtain an interactive connection to your MySQL server, using phpMyAdmin or a similar command-line tool.  While your pdf-creation process is running, repeatedly issue this command

```
   SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

It presents an `INFO` column showing the active MySQL query for each connection. It also shows each query's elapsed `time` in milliseconds. If you have queries that run for many hundreds of milliseconds, you might consider using MySQL's
`EXPLAIN` command to analyze those queries. Often adding an appropriate index to a MySQL table can dramatically speed things up.

*Is the machine running your PDF program short on RAM?* use a performance monitor like *nix `top` or Windows perfmon to take a look.

*Is your 40-page report, simply put, a huge job to create?* If so, you might consider switching to a faster report-generation program than PHP + TCPDF.

Comment: Hi Ollie, 
I have considered all the points listed in http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php ,  still no luck.  MySQL part I have to try your suggestions but these queries were there before also.  Thanks